# Second Order Non-homogeneous Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the DE

$y''-4y'+4y=e^{2x}$

The general solution to the corresponding homogeneous equation is,

$y_h(x)=e^{2x}(A+Bx)$

How do I find a particular solution $y_p(x)$ that fits with this?

Comment: Before we do this, please check whether you have the right DE.  If you do, the solution of the homogeneous equation is not quite right.

Comment: the solution of the homogeneous equation is ok

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/second/variation/variation.html

Comment: @pedja, you really believe $x\mapsto\mathrm e^{2x}$ solves the homogenous equation? Wow.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You're right, the equation was $y''-4y'+4y=e^{2x}$ , not $y''+4y'+4y=e^{2x}$ . Sorry about that.

Comment: @Didier,you are right,it should be $e^{-2x}$,instead $e^{2x}$

Comment: Are you allowed to use Laplace transform?

Comment: @percusse No. I feel I should have specified a little more. This is a question from an introductory single variable calculus course. It is not homework, I've already taken the exam. I just don't get this question, and the course book states "techniques for solving non-homogenous equations are beyond the scope of this book", which irks me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a method called "the method of undetermined coefficients" that deals with such equations. Normally, when you see $e^{2x}$ on the right-hand side you try $y_p = Ae^{2x}$, plug it in, then solve for $A$. However, since $2$ is a double root of the characteristic equation $r^2 - 4r + 4 = 0$, you have to try $y_p = Ax^2 e^{2x}$ instead. If you plug this in, and solve for $A$, you obtain $A = {1 \over 2}$ and therefore $y_p = {1 \over 2}x^2 e^{2x}$.

Answer (score 1):

$y^{\prime \prime} -4y^{\prime} + 4y = e^{2x} \quad \Rightarrow \quad (D^2 - 4D + 4)y = e^{2x} \quad \Rightarrow$

$(D -2)^2y = e^{2x} \quad \Rightarrow \quad y = \frac{1}{(D - 2)^2}e^{2x} = e^{2x}\frac{1}{D^2}\cdot 1 = \frac{x^2}{2}e^{2x}$